# TensorFlow: got logits shape [1,10] and labels shape [2]

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am using TensorFlow functional API for training the model. The dataset I am using is handwritten data with two digits in a single image with 2 labels each image.

I can't figure out what error is occurring during code execution. Help me out.

**Label output layer look like [output1, output2]**

[Training Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQfG3.png)

[Screen shot of CSV label file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSPKy.png)

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

directory = "D:\\tensorflow\\train_images\\"
df = pd.read_csv("train.csv")

file_paths = df.iloc[:,0].values
labels = df.iloc[:,1:].values

ds_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((file_paths, labels))

def read_image(image_file, label):
    image = tf.io.read_file(directory + image_file)
    image = tf.image.decode_image(image, channels=1, dtype=tf.float32)
    return image, label

ds_train = ds_train.map(read_image).batch(2)

input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(64, 64, 1))

x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(input)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
output1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='first_layer')(x)
output2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='second_layer')(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=[output1, output2])

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
              optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(ds_train, epochs=2, verbose=1)
```

Error

```
Epoch 1/2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Tensorflow/custom dataset for images.py", line 33, in <module>
    model.fit(ds_train, epochs=2, verbose=1)
  File "C:\Users\Devanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1100, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\Devanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 828, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Devanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 888, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Devanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2942, in __call__
    return graph_function._call_flat(
  File "C:\Users\Devanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1918, in _call_flat
    return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
  File "C:\Users\Devanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 555, in call
    outputs = execute.execute(
  File "C:\Users\Devanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [1,10] and labels shape [2]
     [[node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits (defined at D:/Tensorflow/custom dataset for images.py:33) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_854]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Comment: what is the `df.first_num.value_counts()` and `df.second_num.value_counts()`?

Comment: Why do you have 2 outputs even though you have 1 label?

Comment: df.first_num.value_counts() and df.second_num.value_counts()  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AQORecxYc0osId3JDRGa1F8Z_s8Bzos3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Why do you have 2 outputs even though you have 1 label?   -.>  I have 2 label for each input, please refer to images I have shared previously.